# Как заморозить нить (Thread) извне?

Tags: java, многопоточность, sleep

Если мы создаем нить, то можем заморозить ее на время в методе run, но каким образом мы можем остановить ее на время извне?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    sleep(400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
//  Здесь должна быть команда которая позволяет заморозить выполнение нити t на 3 секунды
    System.out.println("Нить t остановлена на 3 секунды");
}
```

UPDATE:
Удалось пока решить вот так, но, может, кто подскажет лучшее решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    class TestThread extends Thread {
        private boolean flag;

        public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    sleep(400);
                    if (flag)
                        sleepMe();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        private void sleepMe() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                flag = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    TestThread t = new TestThread();
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    t.setFlag(true);
    System.out.println("Нить t остановлена на 3 секунды");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не существует универсального безопасного способа приостановки/прерывания потока в Java. По этой же причине метод `stop`, `suspend`, `resume` объявлены `deprecated`. Более подробно почему это так описано [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Предполагается, что приостановка/прерывание потока должно происходить по согласованию между потоком, вызывающим прерывание и потоком который должен быть прерван. Определение API и реализации кооперативного взаимодействие приостановки/прерывания для каждого конкретного случая должно быть свое и определяется программистом.

Поэтому предложенный Вами вариант с:

```
if (flag)
  sleepMe();
```

это и будет самым правильное решение. Единственное, что переменная `flag` должна быть `volatile`.